# Creating a notification-esque card based layout in an app

Tags: android, wear-os

I'd like to develop an app for viewing specific data in the form of cards, similar to how notifications are (minus the collapsed state by default, obviously), in which a user could swipe up and down to see information in the same way that they do in notifications.

I've tried wrapping `CardFragment`s within a `FrameLayout` wrapped in a `ScrollView`, but the cards do not move and are static. I've also tried using a single `FrameLayout` defined in the XML, and creating a new `TextView` inside of a `CardFrame` and adding that `CardFrame` programatically, but scrolling is quite broken in that it swipes horizontally and over-swiping closes the app, and the cards themselves are esentially 10x600 rectangles with no text in them.

Is there any way to do such a thing? Apologizes if there's something I'm missing, I'm quite new to the Android API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `GridViewPager` which is part of **Android Wear** support library.

Here is a link to a tutorial. You want to remove one dimension.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/2d-picker.html